# Facebook Login with FB.ui not loading in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook

I'm trying to use a facebook FB.ui() call with the stream.publish method. Everything works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari.  However, in Internet Explorer I get a connection problem. It seems to be the same error you would get when internet connection is down. Attached is a screenshot of the error. Any ideas why this isn't working in IE? I can't find any answers with google.

I can't post an image but it is the "Internet Explorer can not display the webpage" error.

Comment: What is the page url it can't display? You can host image on imageshack.us and provide a link.

Comment: I get the same exact error... Hope to see some answers! +1

Answer (score 1):

Going to throw something out there because it sounds similar to what you're asking.  Does the following link sound related to your problem?  They're talking about what appears to possibly be a bug, it's when using FB.ui() with stream.publish, and only appears to be an issue in internet explorer.

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=72823

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem which you are talking about and got it fixed.

My code looks like this.

FB.ui({ method: 'stream.publish',message: '',attachment: { name: 'type something', caption: '', href: 'url', media : [ { type:'image', src:'some url', href:' url '}], properties: {'some property': { 'text': some name, 'href': ''}} }, action_links: [{ text: 'some text', href: ' url' }]},function(response) { if (!response || response.error) { } else {    } } );

The are two problem which one needs to fix:

Problem 1:

The above code **should not have any trailing comma** in JavaScript or at the best you can type it in a single line. I had two commas which are extra.There are numerous post across internet which states this "Trailing comma is a great problem in IE".

More over,I felt that with respect to FF, Safari, Chrome trailing comma errors are allowed (lot of post mention this) and they run perfect. With respect to IE, it is a strict NO NO....

Problem 2

I see lots of code across the internet that the above function call can be written as follows "FB.ui({ **display: 'iframe**'...." or  FB.ui({ **display: 'popup**'.... or FB.ui({ **display: 'others**'....  All the codes works perfectly with respect to FF, Safari and Chrome but with respect to IE,loops over.

Solution to problem 2 is to remove the name-pair value (  display: 'iframe or display: 'popup' or display: 'others').